# The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration, mapped-folder

Inside windows 10 machines i am trying to map a SharePoint Online document library as a network map drive. when i tried to do the following; Go to This PC >> Right click on Network >> Map network drive:-

[image]

Enter the sharepoint online document library url as follow:-

[image]

but i got this error:-

[image]

now i read this article @ [Mapping SharePoint Libraries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcf0963a-7eb3-42f3-bf65-998cc586014c/mapping-sharepoint-libraries?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) >> so i added the sharepoint online site as trusted site >> i login to sharepoint using IE >> now this worked on one machine while it stay failed on another.. so can anyone advice how i can map a sharepoint online document library as a mapped network drive inside windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OneDrive sync client, instead. IE support, which is required to get mapped drives working, will be dropped early next year.

Comment: but our users want to have the desktop feel when working with sharepoint document libraries,, same experience when they worked with network drives

Comment: You get that with sync'ed Doc Libs. While it isn't a _drive letter_, it is present in Windows Explorer like any other folder in Windows. I would not expect WebDAV to have much life after the removal of support for IE in March 2021.

Comment: so you mean mapping a sharepoint online document library as a mapped network drive is no more considered a solid and future-proof approach?

Comment: It has never been solid and it isn't future-proof.